# Sass map not passing string through variable

Tags: css, sass, each, node-sass

I am trying to create a sass map to apply an icon class to a nested element.

My elements are a div (which will have the class applied) and a span inside that "holds" the icon:

```
<div class="pboi-tour_adventure">
   <span></span>
</div>
```

In actuality, it's part of an AngularJS ng-for, if that matters:

```
<div class="icon-sample" ng-repeat="icon in maps.icons">
    <div class="{{icon}}">
       <span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, following the [guidance in this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-sass-maps/), I am using a sass map and an each loop:

```
$poi-icons: (
  tour_adventure: "\e96c",
  tour_beach: "\e96d",
  tour_tourist_attractions: "\e96e",
  tour_tourist_infomation: "\e96f"
);

@each $name, $icon in $poi-icons {
.pboi-#{$name} {
  span::before {
    content: $icon;
  }
 }
}
```

My issue is that when I inspect the html, there is clearly no "before" pseudo element in the inspector, and the compiled css is

```
.pboi-tour_adventure span::before { content: ""; }
```

When I expect it to be:

```
.pboi-tour_adventure span::before { content: "\e96c"; }
```

Of course, the icon is not working because of this.

**NOTE:** Even if I flatten it out to match the example in the article:

```
  @each $name, $icon in $poi-icons {
   .pboi-#{$name}::before {
     content: $icon;
   }
 }
```

The same thing happens.

### Simplified case:

I put this into Sassmeister:

```
$foo: 'bar';

$icons: (
 busi_ATM: 'foo',
 busi_bank: $foo,
 busi_business: '\e902'
); 

@each $name, $icon in $icons {
 .pboi-#{$name}:before {
    content: $icon;
   }
}
```

and I get

```
.pboi-busi_ATM:before {
   content: "foo";
 }

.pboi-busi_bank:before {
  content: "bar";
}

.pboi-busi_business:before {
   content: "";
 }
```

Why does Sass pass through the first 2 strings but not `'\e902'`?

Also, and more confusing, is when I use the loop the `:before` shows up in the compiled CSS file, but not in the Web Inspector in the browser.  This I don't get at all.

Comment: what is the font associated with your content?

Comment: an icomoon app font.  it's irrelevant, as the character codes are not being passed to the css.  It should simply pass the "\e69e" straight through to the css.

Comment: Sass has a problem of parsing unicode characters, the result will always return a square box which is just an escaped code of the original. But that shouldn't prevent the icon from rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Sass converts the characters internally to the exact ligature/symbol/icon. That's the reason you are seeing a ""; in the inspector. It doesn't mean Sass is not able to parse the character. It means that those characters are not readable in the developer tools.

If for some reason you are seeing the same box in the output, then you are not setting the font properly, or your font is still trying to load. You can check the computed glyph in dev tools to verify what font is loaded.

If you still want to see the actual Unicode, then  you can do a simple test and verify it. you can pass only 'e902' and append the '\' in front of it. I have attached the snippet for it

```
@charset 'UTF-8';
$poi-icons: (
  tour_adventure: "e96c",
  tour_beach: "e96d",
  tour_tourist_attractions: "e96e",
  tour_tourist_infomation: "e96f"
);
@each $name, $icon in $poi-icons {

.pboi-#{$name} {
  span::before {
    content: unquote("\"")+unquote(str-insert($icon,"\\", 1))+unquote("\"");
  }
 }
}
```

reference sass issue:
https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1395

Comment: When I use the loop, it does not even _generate_ the `:before` element in the inspector.  There's nothing to even inspect.  If I do it without the loop, one at a time, I see exactly what you say, and the icon works.  I can't figure out why the loop is not creating the pseudo element at all.

Comment: @Steve are you sure there isn't any typo, i tried creating a sample in codepen https://codepen.io/pen/YQQyJQ

Comment: @Steve or is it version specific. what is the node-sass and sass version you are using?

Comment: "gulp-sass": "3.1.0", "node-sass": "3.13.0",

Comment: i updated node-sass to 4.5.  As you can see, there is no `before` in the inspector.  http://jmp.sh/JCXV10H

Comment: @Steve. I am not sure if this is the issue. but you are having '.pboi- ' in the code where as in the markup the class name is 'pbpoi-'

Comment: That was an error in my sample code for SE. I fixed it. The real code used an AngularJS ng-for.